# Drawable issue with theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-drawable

When building my app, I started just using the Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen theme. I built all my layouts for the whole app like this, and got things to look how I want them. Some drawables used in the layouts have their size specifically set, and others are set to wrap_content.

I then decided to switch to the Holo light theme. When I do this, all the drawables used in layouts that are set to wrap_content end up larger. Almost as if they are pulling from a larger bucket. In fact, some look like they've been stretched.

[image: Holo Based Theme]

[image: Default PreHolo Theme]

I know the background is black in the older theme one, but that's not an issue (this is actually a layout file that is included in another layout). Obviously there's quite a difference in size between the two.

Comment: are these your images, or are they android:drawable images?

Comment: They are my own images.

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: It's set to 8 right now.

Comment: Where exactly do you store drawables?

Answer (score 1):

Here is just my guess based on what I read in this thread.

It can be because you use those images as background property of `Button` views. This is not safe because depending on default margin values - which are defined in the Theme - `Buttons` can stretch background images as they need to. If this is the case, then you need to use `ImageButton` views instead and use `setImage*()` method to assign images. There you can use `scaleType` property as it was mentioned by Carlos Robeles.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind, is that the different themes has different values for the default`android:scaleType` attribute of the image views.

Please, try specifying the attribute as some that is good for you, and see what happens using the 2 different themes. For example you can use `android:scaleType="center"`, so your ImageViews would be something like

```
   <ImageView 
          android:scaleType="center"
          android:width="wrap_content"
          android:height="wrap_content"
          android:src="...
```

Yo can take a look at the different scale types  in the ImageView reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType

It is not easy to understand what's the meaning of every type, so the best is to take a minute to play with them

Comment: I'll try it at some point, but the most of the ones I have issue with are actually Buttons, not ImageViews.

Comment: I see that i didnt explain it well in my last comment. Instead of buttom, you have ImageButtom that extends ImageView so you can use these atributtes and everything else is the same.   Also you could try defining your backgroundhttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: @Ryan are those Buttons or ImageButtons?

Comment: I understand that he has buttons, but what i say is that there is imagebutton, so all the buttons it could be easily changed to imagebuttons

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that for some reason, the Holo theme is rendering your images in a lower resolution than Light. I mean that for instance you have your drawables in the `drawable-xhdpi` and Holo is treating them as `drawable-hdpi`. In fact, I don't have any evidence of that, but recently I've been messing around with resolutions and the difference seems very familiar to me.

If you don't have your drawables in the `drawable-xxhdpi` (the biggest resolution) folder, you could try putting them into a higher lever resolution folder, to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

From android's source code, see https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml
The style which your button will be used in `Holo.Light` is

> ```
> <style name="Widget.Holo.Light.Button" parent="Widget.Button">
>     <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default_holo_light</item>
>     <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
>     <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_holo_light</item>
>     <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
>     <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
> </style>
> ```

See the last two lines. It has default `minHeight` and `minWeight`. That's why your button is stretched.

Solutions
1. Set `minHeight` and `minWidth` of your `Button` to 0.
2. Use a custom style like this.

```
<style name="MyHoloLightButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

3. Use a `ImageButton`, and set your images by `setImage*`(not `setBackround*`) method.